# shall we set continuous integration for laravel without unitest in jenkins.?

Tags: laravel, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, laravel-jetstream

I try to build a laravel project and I want to setup continuous integration using jenkins, How should I create a project in jenkins of laravel. And shall we build without unit testing in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

There are some videos here about how to setup Jenkins (and Docker) for a Laravel project https://serversforhackers.com/s/jenkins-blue-ocean

You can also use the free tier on [Chipper CI for Laravel CI](https://chipperci.com).